# Italicized characters violating margins, even with microtype option [protrusion=false]

Tags: koma-script, geometry, microtype

Pretty self-explanatory.  I'm dealing with a gov't agency which uses automated checks for uploaded documents.  I was going in circles trying to find margin violations.  I expected `microtype` to be able to fix this by setting `[protrusion=false]`, but no.

Looking for solid solutions here. Is this just a BUG?

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[usegeometry,letterpaper,fontsize=11,titlepage=no,footheight=0in]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[protrusion=false,expansion=true,kerning=true,babel=true,final]{microtype}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\pagestyle{empty}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries}

\title{Example Text (Check for Margin Violations)}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\subsection*{Project Description}
Here is a sentence whose tail will violate the margin if it is italicized where the line breaks. \textit{See, if the 
line breaks near the ``f,'' then that character violates the margin.}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image: resulting PDF]

zoomed:
[image: zoomed at margin]

Comment: That seems like an outlandish requirement. It is quite normal for glyphs to partly protrude outside their bounding box and has nothing to do with `microtype` per se (try `\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\fbox{f}`). You _could_ abuse `microtype` to keep the glyphs inside the margins (e.g., `\SetProtrusion{font = */*/*/it/*}{ f = {-100,-500}}`) but it would seem quite a laborious task to go through all possible fonts and glyphs...

Comment: Couldn't you just make the text block a couple of points smaller?

Comment: Have you tried just removing `protrusion=false` entirely?

Comment: @Mico That would only result in many more glyphs protruding into the margin (or "violating" it). The OP seems to want something like negative protrusion.

Comment: @Robert, @Mico: Thanks for your thoughts.  Yes, it is outlandish, yes, I can (and did) just increase margins to compensate, and yes, I did try omitting `protrusion=false` to no avail. I'm wondering whether this is a bug. I assumed that `protrusion=false` should disable all protrusion...

Comment: no, why would it be a bug? As I said in my first comment, it is normal for glyphs (especially in italics) to stick out of their box. And `protrusion=false` simply switches off all protrusion-related adjustments, so it would be the same as not loading `microtype` at all in this respect.

Comment: ... In other words, the protruding "f" has nothing to do with `microtype` but is just the result of tex's typesetting engine doing its job.

Comment: @Robert, I see.  That detail was lost on me.  Reading the microtype documentation led me to expect that `protrusion=false` should prevent any incidences of protrusion.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a margin violation is extending the text outside the stipulated margin. I assume that the font type and size are regulated as well.

Then, as practical solution, you could  increase the right margin a bit. (At least for paragraphs in italics).

In this experiment I used a 74.3 point right margin (1 inch = 72.27 points, 2 points approximately 0.028 inch).
The original text width went from 469.76pt down to 467.725pt

The 469.76 point long blue rulers mark the original left edge. It seems that this expansion of the right margin is enough to keep the italics f and others within the allowed official margins, without affecting the output of the TeX paragraph typesetting (third figure), at least in this particular case.

[image: d]

[image: dz]

[image: e]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[usegeometry,letterpaper,fontsize=11,titlepage=no,footheight=0in]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[protrusion=false,expansion=true,kerning=true,babel=true,final]{microtype}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries}

\title{Example Text (Check for Margin Violations)}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\subsection*{Project Description}

\newgeometry{left=1in,top=1in,right=74.3pt,bottom=1in,nohead,nofoot}
{\noindent\color{blue!20}\rule{469.755pt}{10pt}}  % 469.76pt = textwidth with 1in left margin

\textit{\kant[1]}

{\noindent\color{blue!20}\rule{469.755pt}{10pt}}

textwidth I = \the\textwidth

\newpage
\newgeometry{left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead,nofoot}   
{\noindent\color{blue!20}\rule{\textwidth}{10pt}}   
    
\textit{\kant[1]}

{\noindent\color{blue!20}\rule{\textwidth}{10pt}}

textwidth II = \the\textwidth       

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Simon-Dispa.  I implemented this workaround as a fix, but still wonder whether this is a bug in `microtype`...